# INSERT unless exist in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have `users` table on my wesite and I want to write function that will take the `email` column and insert it to a diffrent table, `mailing_list`, but only if the email isn't exist in there.

For the question you can assume each table have this columns: `ID`,`username`, `email`.

This is my current code:

```
$get_mails = $db->query("SELECT `username`,`email`,`email_approved`,`ver` FROM `users` WHERE ver='yes' && email_approved='1'");
while ($mails = $get_mails->fetch_assoc())  {
    if ($db->query("SELECT `email` FROM `mailing_list` WHERE email='".$mails['email']."'")->num_rows == 0)  {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO `mailing_list` VALUES('','".$mails['email']."','".$mails['username']."')");         
    }
}
```

As you can see it's not very efficient. There is a way to do it in the `INSERT` query itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One (kinda dirty) solution is to put an unique index on the `email` field in `mailing list`, this will prevent double entries so you won't have to do a select query first.

Edit, example:

```
$db->query
(
    "INSERT IGNORE INTO `mailing_list` 
    SELECT '',email,username FROM `users`
    WHERE ver = 'yes' AND email_approved = '1'"
);
```

Comment: not dirty at all, it should be enforced on the database level as well as the app level.

Comment: I second @IMB on this one, it's not dirty, it's actually the only sensible thing to do. +1

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `INSERT ... SELECT` approach which would allow you to use a join for filtering as well as execute all inserts with a single query instead of iteratively querying.

That might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO mailing_list (email, username)
SELECT u.email, u.username
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN mailing_list AS ml
  ON u.email = ml.email
WHERE
  /* this filters to only those records that don't exist in mailing_list */
  ml.email IS NULL
  /* these are conditions from your initial query as shown */
  AND u.ver = 'yes'
  AND u.email_approved = '1'
```

For the query to be optimized, you would need indexes on `u.email`, `u.ver`, `u.email_approved`, and `ml.email`.  This also assumes you have an autoincrement index on `ml.id`, such that when insert is made without specifying value for this field, it well get the next number in sequence.

A tip for your future coding - when you find yourself wanting to make queries within loops, you should look at the code more closely, as there is oftentimes a better approach to simplify your data access.

Comment: Reason for downvote - the answer isn't optimal solution at all. The only sensible approach is placing a unique index and doing what vinz posted in his answer. Due to nonexistent unique index, it's possible to end up with duplicate records.

Comment: @N.B. I would think you would want a unique index on mailing_list.email in any case. Even without a unique index on that column my approach would work just fine, and this specific query would have no means by which it could introduce duplicates in that table, as you are only inserting rows where no value for the email address exists in the mailing list table.  Duplicates could certainly be introduced in other ways, but not based on my query.

Comment: @N.B. Performance between my query and his would differ based on how much difference exists between tables. Take an example where you have 1M rows in users table similar number of rows in mailing list table to where there may only be a relatively small number of emails in users that are not in mailing list.  My approach would likely perform much better as you would not be trying to insert all 1M rows. My approach would only attempt insert where the differences exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this query: First query will stay as it is and this query is for next 2 queries
INSERT INTO `mailing_list` (email) select ".$mails['email']." from mailing_list where (select count(.$mails['email'].) from test1 where  name1 = '.$mails['email'].') = 0 limit 1;
```

Sample query:

```
Insert into mailing_list (email) select "z.y@z.com" from mailing_list where (select count(email) from mailing_list where email='z.y@z.com' and ) = 0 limit 1;
```

This will give the email string as output

```
select "z.y@z.com" from mailing_list where
```

This will verify where email exist in the table (if the count is 0 new email will be inserted, if mot it wont insert

```
select count(email) from mailing_list where email='z.y@z.com') = 0
```

This is to limit the not matched email

```
limit 1
```